# How to change a variable with a different variable in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

What I'm trying to do is make an idle animation for my player. What I want to happen is use one of my variables as an event so when called, will change a variable with a variable inside that holds an image, will change to a different image variable, but I'm not sure how to do that yet. I've watched tutorials on how to play animations, but I built my code really badly, and now can't do any of what the tutorials are saying. This is part of my code to show what I'm trying to do:

```
player_image_right = pygame.image.load('player_animations/Idle/maincharacteridle1.png').convert()
player_image_right = pygame.transform.scale(player_image_right, (54, 54))

timer = pygame.time.set_timer('my event that im going to use to change the variable', 500)
```

---

```
if not event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if player_image == player_image_right and timer == 500:           
            player_image = player_image_right2
        if player_image == player_image_right2 and timer == 500:            
            player_image = player_image_right
```

Comment: You can use a timer to send events that then trigger a change in animation. Here's an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63147361/2280890) that you may find helpful.

Comment: Store the images of the animation in a list, then index it using the `time` module and a `start` variable: `image = images[int((time.time() - start) * animation_frequence) % len(images)]`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use a list instead of holding multiple files in different variables. For example:

```
def get_image(path, scale):
    image = pygame.image.load(path).convert()
    image= pygame.transform.scale(image, scale)
    return image

player_images = []
player_idle_index = 0
player_images.append(get_image('player_animations/Idle/maincharacteridle1.png', (54,54))
player_images.append(get_image('player_animations/Idle/maincharacteridle2.png', (54,54))


if not event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    if timer % 500 == 0:  # check if half a second has passed
        if player_idle_index == len(player_images)-1:
            player_idle_index = 0  #reset the index if end of list reached
        else:
            player_idle_index += 1   # move on to next image
```

And then when you want to display your image, instead of using blit on a variable, you would do something like:

```
gameDisplay.blit(player_images[player_idle_index], (x,y))
```

where `gameDisplay` is your display. You should only display the idle image if the player is idle, so maybe add a `isIdle = True` somewhere in your code to check if the player is moving or not, and whether or not to display the idle state of the player.
This technique allows you to add as many idle images as you want, and is part of the basics of animation. Here is some more information: https://www.techwithtim.net/tutorials/game-development-with-python/pygame-tutorial/pygame-animation/